# How to put two unique fields in spring boot mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to create two unique fields in spring mongodb but without success I'm using:

> @CompoundIndex(def = "{'product_id': 1, 'ip': 1}", unique = true)

Follow my entire class:

```
@Setter @Getter 
@CompoundIndex(def = "{'product_id': 1, 'ip': 1}", unique = true)
@Document(collection = "star_rating")
public class Star_ratingMongo extends AuditMetadata implements Persistable<Long>{
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("product_id")
    private Long product_id;

    @JsonProperty("id_collection")
    private Long emberId;

    public Long getEmberId() {
        return product_id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ip")
    private String ip;

    @JsonProperty("star")
    private Integer star;


    @Override
    @Nullable
    public Long getId() {
        return product_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
         return !persisted;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What are you experiencing? Will the index be created?

Comment: I want that when I insert it, I don't duplicate the two keys

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

To solve the problem I found the following code:

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("mongoTemplate")
public class CollectionsConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initIndexes() {
        mongoTemplate.indexOps(Star_ratingMongo.class)
            .ensureIndex(new Index().on("product_id", Sort.Direction.DESC)
                    .on("ip", Sort.Direction.DESC).unique());

    }
}
```